# Прокрутить страницу до определенного элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Доброго времени суток.** 
Сделал форму отправки данных.
Форма получилось длинной, и в мобильной версии пока заполнишь все данные и доберешься до кнопки "Отправить", то что на верху не видно, приходится прокручивать руками.
 Моя идея заключается в том, что бы если например юсер забыл указать рейтинг звезд, который находится в самом верху формы, я вывожу блок с уведомлением и анимационно прокручиваю страницу до этого уведомления.
 Вывод блока с уведомлением, я уже сделал, но не могу понять как сделать анимационную прокрутку на этот элемент.
Вот js:

```
$(".btn-send").on('click', function(e){
   if ( product_rating == 0 ){
        error = 1;
        $("label#select_error").show();

    } else {
        error = 0;
        $("label#select_error").hide();
    }
    if ( error ){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
})
```

Вот html:

```
<label class="myerror" id="select_error" style="color:#ff7000"><b> Установите пожалуйста рейтинг.</b></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var form = $('#form');

// Генерация длинной формы для примера
for (i = 50; i > 0; i--) {
  form.prepend($('<div' + (i == 10 ? ' class="error"' : '') + '><label>' + i + ':</label><input></div>'));
}

// Код непосредственно относящийся к вопросу
var modal = $('#modal');
form.submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  modal.animate({
    scrollTop: modal.scrollTop() + $(".error").first().offset().top - modal.offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#form div {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#form div.error {
  color: red;
}

label {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#modal {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modal">
  <form id="form">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Моя форма в модальном окне, сейчас прокручивается то что за модальным окном. А как сделать что бы прокрутилось внутри формы?

Comment: @Dolphin заменить `$('html, body')` на селектор вашего модального окна.

Comment: я пробовал так, но в таком случае вообще не скролит.

Comment: @Dolphin дополнил, проверяйте.

Comment: В консоле выдает ошибку modal.scrollTop is not a function

Comment: При запуске моего примера? Или при запуске вашего кода?

Comment: При запуске в моем коде

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev заработало. Спасибо за помощь! =)))

Answer (score 2):

Думаю принцип понятен.

```js
$('.item span').on('click', function(){
  let data = $(this).data('goto'),
      coor = $('.item.'+data).offset().top;
      
  $('html, body').scrollTop(coor);
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #ddd;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #aaa;
}

.item span {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="item">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <span data-goto='i2'>Пролистать до 2</span>
</div>

<div class="item i2">
  <h3>2</h3>
  <span data-goto='i3'>Пролистать до 3</span>
</div>

<div class="item i3">
  <h3>3</h3>
  <span data-goto='i4'>Пролистать до 4</span>
</div>

<div class="item i4">
  <h3>4</h3>
  <span data-goto='i5'>Пролистать до 5</span>
</div>

<div class="item i5">
  <h3>5</h3>
</div>
```

---

Так называемый "плавный скролл"

```js
$('.item span').on('click', function(){
  let data = $(this).data('goto'),
      coor = $('.item.'+data).offset().top;
      
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: coor+'px'
  }, 700);
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #ddd;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #aaa;
}

.item span {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="item">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <span data-goto='i2'>Пролистать до 2</span>
</div>

<div class="item i2">
  <h3>2</h3>
  <span data-goto='i3'>Пролистать до 3</span>
</div>

<div class="item i3">
  <h3>3</h3>
  <span data-goto='i4'>Пролистать до 4</span>
</div>

<div class="item i4">
  <h3>4</h3>
  <span data-goto='i5'>Пролистать до 5</span>
</div>

<div class="item i5">
  <h3>5</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: хороший пример +